# Wrong type argument: commandp cscope

Tags: helm, commands, tags

**My question** is how to let the command `SPC-m-c-C`get the function name automatically?

I am using 0.200.10@25.3.1 (spacemacs), on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
I am using cscope layer, it is great but with one function cannot be used normally.

Every time when I press `SPC-m-c-C` to call `helm-cscope-find-calling-this-funtcion`, I get error `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, helm-cscope-find-calling-this-funtcion`
I then do `M-x helm-cscope-find-calling-this-funtcion`, it will then ask me to input the function name and after I input the function name, everything works well.

I have also searched for some similar questions, but they are not the problem I am facing.
[ref001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/wrong-type-argument-commandp-error-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key)
[ref002](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36139/c-x-c-f-results-in-the-error-message-wrong-type-argument-commandp-counsel-fi)
[ref003](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/command-works-with-m-x-but-gives-wrong-type-argument-commandp-when-calling-th)

My config file for cscope

```
(defun cscope/init-helm-cscope ()
  (use-package helm-cscope
    :defer t
    :init
    (defun spacemacs/setup-helm-cscope (mode)
      "Setup `helm-cscope' for MODE"
      (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode mode
        "cc" 'helm-cscope-find-called-function
        "cC" 'helm-cscope-find-calling-this-funtcion
        "cd" 'helm-cscope-find-global-definition
        "ce" 'helm-cscope-find-egrep-pattern
        "cf" 'helm-cscope-find-this-file
        "cF" 'helm-cscope-find-files-including-file
        "cr" 'helm-cscope-find-this-symbol
        "cx" 'helm-cscope-find-this-text-string))
    :config
    (defadvice helm-cscope-find-this-symbol (before cscope/goto activate)
      (evil--jumps-push))))
```

Comment: Is it really spelled "*funtcion*"? The error tells you that that function is not a command, which means that it does not have an `interactive` spec. But you can apparently invoke it using `M-x`, which requires a command.

Can you repro the problem when starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? What does `C-h k M-x` tell you `M-x` is bound to? There seems to be some info missing from this question.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really a wrong spelling and they have already updated this bug in the develop branch https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/develop/layers/%2Btags/cscope/packages.el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake:

`helm-cscope-find-calling-this-funtcion`

The word is spelled `function`

I'm not using these features so I don't know for sure, but I suspect that the problem will be solved if you fix that name.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you very much.